# Adding a group member fails with the application level "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All" permissions - works with "Group.ReadWrite.All"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to msdocs it should be sufficient to have the "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All" application level permissions to add members to a security group

I get an authorization error (see below) - it works as expected if I grant the "Group.ReadWrite.All" permissions

Did I miss something obvious here?

Language is PowerShell - connected to the Graph API v1.0 with the "client_credentials" grant type

Error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "71b06588-f9a2-48ef-ac3f-5223899cad68",
      "date": "2020-01-03T09:30:31"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Add member` endpoint documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) states that for `Application` permission type one the following permissions are required:

> `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All`, `Group.ReadWrite.All` and
>   `Directory.ReadWrite.All`

But, it appears, it also varies based on *group type*:

- for `Office365` group, one of the following permissions are
  sufficient: `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All`
- while for `Security` group, along with `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` permission, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` needs to be specified as well

So, the solution would be to specify permission `Directory.ReadWrite.All` along with  `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: Thanks Vadim - must be due to the group type being a security group then (I have it working with `Group.ReadWrite.All` for a security group though  - I haven't granted `Directory.ReadWrite.All`)

Comment: I have principal (application) who is owner of the group. Principal is used by my azure devops connection. I would like to add member to the security group from devops pipeline. Why cannot I add member group from pipeline. Adding Directory RW All permission is not possible due to policies. It makes no sense